# Where can I use the initial conditions to this general differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find in the form of an integral, the solution of the equation
>   $$\alpha\frac{dy}{dt}+y=f(t)$$ that satisfies $y\rightarrow 0$ as
>   $t\rightarrow -\infty$. Here $f(t)$ is a general function and 
>   $\alpha$ is a positive constant.

I'm just a little confused as I get the solution
$y=\frac1{\alpha}e^{-\frac1{\alpha}t}\int e^{\frac1{\alpha}t}f(t) \space dt$
and I don't know how to use the initial conditions- where can I put them in?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we have

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{t/\alpha}y(t)\right)=\frac1\alpha e^{t/\alpha}f(t) \tag 1$$

with $\lim_{t\to -\infty}y(t)=0$.  Integrating $(1)$ from $-\infty$ to $t$ yields

$$y(t)=\frac1\alpha e^{-t/\alpha}\int_{-\infty}^t e^{t'/\alpha}f(t')\,dt'$$

Comment: Ah got it. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  And Happy Holidays!  -Mark

Comment: You too. Just one thing though. I'm probably being incredibly thick here, but how do we know that this tends to $0$ as $t\rightarrow -\infty$? I can see that that the integral will tend to $0$ as the limits approach each other, but the $e^{-t/a}$ will tend to infinity, so how do we know that the integral tends to zero fast enough?

Comment: And that is a great point.  Note that in order for the integral to converge, we must require $f(t)\to 0$ as $t\to -\infty$.  Then, note that $$\lim_{t\to - \infty}\frac{\frac1\alpha \int_{-\infty}^t e^{-t'/\alpha}f(t')\,dt'}{e^{t/\alpha}}$$is of the indeterminate form $0/0$.  Applying L'Hospital's Rule we have $$\lim_{t\to -\infty} \frac{\frac1\alpha e^{t/\alpha}f(t)}{\frac1\alpha e^{t/\alpha}}=\lim_{t\to -\infty}f(t)=0$$

Comment: Excellent thank you very much